# Laravel Eloquent getting property of nested eager loading that may or may not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a user with its 'transactions' filtered after certain date.
However, the relation hasCustomers, customers, or transactions may or may not exist.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
    $user = User::with('hasCustomers.customers.transactions', function ($q) use ($filter){
        $q->whereDate('created_at', '>', $filter);
    })->find($user_id);
```

However it throws an error `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`.
The expected output is to get this 'user' properties with 'transactions' after certain date filter (if 'transactions' exists).

Any leads?

EDIT:
This returns properly, but the date is not filtered because the 'with' is not filtered.

```
User::with('hasCustomers.customers.transactions')
->whereHas('hasCustomers.customers.transactions', function ($q) use ($filter){
    $q->whereDate('created_at', '>', $filter);
})->find($user_id);
```

EDIT:
It was syntax error, I should have used array. This works perfectly.

```
$dateFilter = function ($q) use ($filter){
        $q->whereDate('created_at', '>', $filter);
    };
$user = User::with(['hasCustomers.customers.transactions' => $dateFilter]->find($user_id);
```

Comment: What's the result of `dd($filter);`?

Comment: show the relations of hasCustomers, customers and transaction

Comment: It is a carbon date Carbon @1553156228 {#1395 ▼
  date: 2019-03-21 08:17:08.0 UTC (+00:00)
}

Comment: hasCustomers returns hasMany customers, customers is the properties of the customers, and each customer hasMany transactions

Comment: Please post the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```php
    User::with('hasCustomers.customers.transactions')
                ->whereHas('hasCustomers', function ($q) use ($filter) {
                    $q->whereHas('customers', function ($q) use ($filter) {
                        $q->whereHas('transactions', function ($q) use ($filter) {
                            $q->whereDate('created_at', '>', $filter);

                        });
                    });
                })->find($user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was syntax error, I should have used array. This works perfectly.

```php
$dateFilter = function ($q) use ($filter){
        $q->whereDate('created_at', '>', $filter);
    };
$user = User::with(['hasCustomers.customers.transactions' => $dateFilter]->find($user_id);
```